# Corrected usage of gcov on executable and static library

Tags: gcc, gcov

I have a very simple example of using gcov:

- `library.cpp` file compiled and turned into `library.a`
- `main.cpp` file compiled into executable and uses `library.a`

All of this done via a simple bash script:

```
g++ -c library.cpp -Wall -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -o library.o
ar rvs library.a library.o
g++ main.cpp -Wall -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage library.a -o main
```

Now at this point I have the folllowing files (ignoring source and build script):

```
library.o
library.gcno
library.a

main.cpp
main
main.gcno
```

So far so good.  Now I run my `main` executable, which creates:

```
main.gcda
library.gcda
```

Again all as expected.  Now for the question - when I run `gcov main.cpp` I don't get any gcov files for library.cpp.  Is that expected?

Do I really need to call `gcov` on every source file I may have at any point in time?  Is there not a way to call the first source file i.e `main.cpp` and have it produce coverage stats for each piece of source `main` goes on to call?

I appear to get gcov files for a lot of core library code that `main.cpp` uses without need to call them directly with gcov (ostream.gov, locale.gcov...) just not `library.gcov`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd call `gcov *.gcno`.